# Puzzle by C type promotion from short to int

Tags: c, types, int, short

I have a question that needs guidance from any expert:

1. As a value with `short` type is passed as an argument to `printf()` function, it'll be automatically promoted to `int` type, that is why the `printf()` function will see the value as `int` type instead of `short` type.
2. So basically `short` type is 16-bits wide, which is `0000000000000000` while `int` type is 32-bits wide, which is `00000000000000000000000000000000`.
3. Let's say I declare a variable call `num` with `short` type and initialise it with a value of -32, that means the most significant bits of the `short` type will be `1`, which is `0000000011100000`.
4. When I pass this value to `printf()`, it'll be converted to `int` type, so it'll become `00000000000000000000000011100000`.
5. In step 4, when it is converted to `int`, the most significant bit is `0`.
6. Why, when I use the `%hd` specifier or even the `%d` specifier, will it still still prompt me for a negative value instead of a positive?

Answer (score 9):

No, short and int are both signed types, so it is promoted by sign extension not 0-byte padding:

```
-32 short =                   11111111 11100000 
-32 int   = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100000
```

leaving the MSB as 1 i.e. negative.

You could fake the behavour you're expecting by casting it unsigned first, e.g.

```
printf("%d", (unsigned short)((short)(-32)));
```

Comment: +1: In 2's complement, this is absolutely correct.  For other representations, something equivalent will occur.

Comment: What Oli says - to be precise when promoting from `short` to `int` the true mathematical value of the number is preserved. In 2's complement and 1s' complement, this means sign extension. In sign-magnitude it means zero-padding to the right of the sign bit.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a short to an int basically replicates the most significate bit of the short into the top 16 bits of the int.  This is why the int is printed as negative.  If you do not want this behaviour using a `ushort`.

Answer (score 2):

As you say it is converted and conversion in this case implies knowlegde. That is the compiler knows how signed short to int conversion work. It does not just append bits in front, it creates a new int with the same value as the short. That's why you get the correct number.